# Excel if all three statements are empty

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to develop a formula that would look for values in three cells N11, N12, N13 and if all three are empty then it would display empty cell. However if at least one of three cells N11 or N12 or N13 has data it would display sum of available values.

Here is the formula I came up with:

```
=IF(OR(N11="";N12="";N13="");"";SUMIF(N11:N13;"<>"""))
```

However it works only if there are all three values available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(N11:N13)=3;"";SUM(N11:N13))
```